# ¿Es mejor usar ADO.NET o EF para manipular objetos de base de datos desde MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Actualmente utilizo Entity Framework para hacer las conexiones a base de datos desde C# con MVC, pero se me hace algo tedioso estar agregándo las tablas y todo al modelo de la base de datos en el proyecto, y si se modifica algo tengo que eliminar y volver a agregar en el caso de los *complex* de procedimientos o funciones.

Ahora empece a utilizar `SqlConnection` y ejecuto directo la consulta o procedimiento.

La pregunta es ¿cuál sería la forma más adecuada de hacerlo en cuanto a rendimiento? y, ¿qué es lo correcto o el deber ser?

Entity Framework:

```
 bdEntities db = new bdEntities();
 var list = (from ex in db.Usuario.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {   id_usuario = ex.UsuarioID,
                    s_Nombre= ex.Nombre,

                }).ToList();
```

ADO.NET:

```
String conexion = ("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=Username;Password=P4ssw0rD");
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
cnn.Open();
string var1, var2;
String consulta = "select Nombre, * from BD..usuario";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, cnn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    var1 = dr["UsuarioID"].ToString();
    var2 = dr["Nombre"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Considero que a nivel de componentes o como tecnología no son un punto de comparación entre uno y otro. Por un lado ADO.NET opera directamente con objetos de base de datos como tablas, vistas, procedimientos mientras que Entity Framework encapsula esos objetos creando un nivel de abstracción superior y opera como una capa intermedia entre la aplicación y la base de datos. Las ventajas de usar EF es que tendrás todo en un solo lugar, si deseas crear una consulta podrás revisar en tiempo de ejecución el resultado, a diferencia de ADO.NET que tendrás que exportar la consulta o usar otras herramie

Comment: ¿cuál sería la forma más adecuada de hacerlo en cuanto a rendimiento? Entre esos dos, ADO tiene mas rendimiento.  ¿qué es lo correcto o el deber ser?  No todo es blanco o negro, todo depende de las necesidades del proyecto. Si te sientes agusto con ado.net úsalo, pero pierdes muchísimas cosas usándolo, aparte que tienes que hacer muchas cosas a mano, en proyectos pequeños no hay mucho problema, pero ahi te quiero ver con proyectos grandes, aparte que con ADO no tienes ayuda del compilador. Aparte hay muchos mas ORMs que EF, si quieres algo ligero tienes Linq2Db (no confundir con Linq2Sql).

Comment: Otr cosa, tienes formas de mantener las entidades sincromizadas con la bdd, no tienes porque modificar a mano las clases, y por otro lado, si cambias la bdd y usas ADO tambien tienes que modifcar las consultas, y eso es peor pues al ser strings el compilador no te ayuda, si se te olvida cambiar alguna consulta, tu aplicación va a tronar, en cambio con un ORM, el compilador te avisa.

Comment: considero que ADO es un buen modelo para manejar conexiones simples, cuando la lógica no necesita ser actualizada constantemente y sobre todo cuando en su mayoría la funcionalidad se encuentra del lado de la base de datos (procedimientos almacenados, funciones, triggers). EF lo veo mas cuando tu modelo y logica estan atados muy intimamente con la logica de tu aplicación. **lo que podría decir es :** EF es un overkill para una App cuyos Requerimientos funcionales no dependen de una la información en la BD. Pero seria lo mas adecuado para en ERM, por ejemplo: Seria de locos usar MVC con CRUD con

Comment: Nótese que en dado caso, los fragmentos de código en la pregunta no realizan la misma función.